# Shell's Increments Worst Case Analysis

Tags: asymptotics, sorting

My textbook claims the worst-case running time of Shellsort with Shell's increments is $Ω(N^2)$, but this analysis is done when $N = 2^m$ for a positive integer $m$. I see why the proof would work for those cases of $N$. The reasoning for the proof does not appear to, in general, hold for arbitrary $N$. However, the definition of $Ω$ requires that the running time be above a multiple of $N^2$ for all $N >$ (some) $k$, which it didn't prove.

I also checked online, and every proof I've seen uses this exact same reasoning. Why is it OK to claim Shell's increment worst case is $Ω(N^2)$? What about the $N$ in  between $2^m$ and $2^{m+1}$? How can I show their running time doesn't fall below some multiple of $N^2$ (if it is even possible)?

A similar proof can be found here: https://codeahoy.com/learn/sortingalgorithmsa/shellsort/ (not my textbook)

Maybe the reasoning extends to arbitrary $N$, but I just don't see it?

Comment: (What if you add items larger than the largest in input so the number of items is the next non-lower power of 2?)

Comment: The claim holds for all $N$ if you can prove that the running time is a growing function of $N$ (or at least, if $N>2^m$ then $T(N)>T(2^m)$.

Answer (score 0):

Every value of $N$ is within a factor of two of a power of two.

In particular, given any $N$, let $N_0$ be the largest power of two such that $N_0 \le N$.  Your textbook apparently proves that the worst-case running time on an input of length $N_0$ is at least $c \cdot N_0^2$.  The worst-case running time only increases with the length of the input (never decreases), so it follows that the worst-case running time on an input of length $N$ is at least $c \cdot N_0^2$.  Notice that $N_0 \ge N/2$, so it follows that the worst-case running time on an input of length $N$ is at least $c \cdot (N/2)^2 \ge (c/4) \cdot N^2$.  Notice that this holds for all $N$.  It follows that the worst-case running time is $\Omega(N^2)$.

Comment: The reasoning for the textbook's proof uses the fact that apart from 1, for $2^k$ $(1 < k < m)$ is even, thus forcing $Ω(N^2)$. However, for a choice of N between $2^m$ and $2^{m+1}$, it's not clear to me that the running time must increase. The reasoning for the proof no longer holds, which could mean there's a more efficient outcome in between, when even and odd indices are not sorted separately before the final "insertion sort" step.

Comment: @GuestUser, OK, good point!  Perhaps you might try to generalize the counterexample (the example of a hard input), e.g., by padding it with extra data at the end to make its length be $N$, or something.  I don't know whether that would work or not.